# QGraphicsView element moving with mouse not smooth

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsview

I have a QGraphicsView element which has no borders, title etc and I want to move it around in the screen. I achieved to move it with the mouse, but it's not smooth, it's jumping around and not following the mouse properly.

```py
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.mouseMovePos = None
    if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        self.mouseMovePos = event.globalPos()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        currPos = self.mapToGlobal(self.pos())
        globalPos = event.globalPos()
        diff = globalPos - self.mouseMovePos
        newPos = self.mapFromGlobal(currPos + diff / 40)
        self.move(newPos)
```

Maybe it is because of performance? Is there a way to make the window smoothly follow my mouse?

Comment: why `diff / 40`?

Comment: Because it's too sensitive. This way i can slow it down, but it is still not smooth.